# Using Vue£ Vite globalProperties in production?

Tags: vue.js, vite

I'm trying to serve my assets through Cloudfront (s3) and so:

I have a env variable that contains the cloudfront URL.
I want to use it globally in my app so I did this:

```js
app.config.globalProperties.$IMAGE_URL = import.meta.env.IMAGE_URL;
app.mount("#app");
```

It works perfectly in local but when I deploy the app. The views are left blank whenever they have `this.$IMAGE_URL` on it. With no error message. The issues comes from that, not Cloudfront. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by using provide and inject to use then

```
// in main.js
app.provide("IMAGE_URL", import.meta.env.IMAGE_URL);
```

```
// in components script setup
import {inject} from 'vue'
const IMAGE_URL = inject("IMAGE_URL");
```

```
// in <img>
:src="`${IMAGE_URL}/path/to/asset`"
```

hope it helps !